# A difficult 2nd order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been doing some revision in dynamics, and I reduced a problem to solving the differential equation (stripping away the constants) given by $$\ddot x = x^2$$

How can I find the general solution for this? It's not something I've seen before, and I got a very strange answer when typing it into Wolfram Alpha, despite the equation's simplicity! Is there a general method for approaching problems like these?

[image: The Wolfram result:]

Comment: It might be useful to include the result you found using Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: multiply by $\dot{x}$ we find
$$
\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}\dot{x}^2 = \dfrac{d}{dt}\frac{x^3}{3}
$$
so we find
$$
\dot{x}^2 = \frac{2x^3}{3} + C
$$
then you get 
$$
\pm\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{2x^3}{3} + C}} =t + C
$$
which will give a strange result. Take a look at this simple equation
$$
y''-xy = 0
$$

Comment: I want to know the story of how that symbol for the elliptic function came to be.

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite second derivative:
$$\ddot x = \frac{d\dot x}{dt}=\frac{d\dot x}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d\dot x}{dx}\dot x = \frac{d(\dot x^2/2)}{dx}.$$
So you have
$$\frac{d(\dot x^2/2)}{dx}=x^2,$$
and hence
$$\frac{\dot x^2}{2} = \frac{x^3}{3}+C/2,$$
where $C$ is some constant. Now we have
$$\pm\dot x = \sqrt{\frac23 x^3+C},$$
and
$$\pm\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac23 x^3+C}}=dt.$$
Integrate it and
$$\pm\int_{x_0}^x \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac23 x^3+C}} = t-t_0$$
Left side is inverse Weierstrass function, and Mathematica was right)